# Count all the documents in MongoDB containing specific item in array

Tags: python, mongodb

I am very new to MongoDB and I really try to understand how I can have an access and count all the instances of documents in my database where I have 'name1' (in the array of names). What should I use - aggregation, find? I tried but failed all the time, can't really find a proper query for it. An example of my document is below. 
I'm using PyMongo as a connection driver.

```
{  
   '_id':ObjectId('599983d47fec3323a8526d74'),
   'name':[  
      {  
         'name1':{  
            'params':[  
               {  
                  'a':'b'
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            'name2':{  
               'params':[  
                  {  
                     'a':'b'
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
```

Comment: Better to change the structure really, but `.find({ "name.name1": { "$exists": true }).count()` does work, albeit without the usage of an index since MongoDB cannot use an index when testing for a "key" rather than a value. Named keys that vary like this are never a really good idea for a database. Nesting arrays is never a great idea either.

Answer (score 0):

Your data model is severely flawed. A key should never be used as a value as this will almost always force you to do weird stuff in your code.

Hence, a more appropriate data model would be

```
{
   "_id": new ObjectId(),
   "names": [
     {
       "name": "name1",
        "params": {
           "a":"b",
           "foo":"bar"
         }
       }
     ]
   }
```

Querying this model becomes a breeze

```
db.yourColl.find({"names.name":"name1"})
```

Note: There is no point in making `params` an array. You can access the individual parameters via object properties of the `params` object.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `$in` operator for an specific field and use `.count()`. For example:

```
db.COLLECTION.find({
    'names': {
        '$in': ['name1']
    }
}).count()
```

Comment: The `$in` operator is not needed. In case the value is an array, a simple `{"names":"name1"}` should be sufficient